# how to sort a list containing filenames?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, listdir

I have a list of ~1000+ values in it. The values are the names of files in a folder which is given by `os.listdir(folder_path)`

code looks like this:

```
import os

folder_path = "some path here"
filelist = os.listdir(folder_path)

print(filelist)
```

Now when I look at the printed list, I see that the list isn't sorted by name. The filenames are something like `["text-1-1.txt","txt-1-23.txt","txt-1-32.txt","txt-1-10.txt","txt-2-1.txt","txt-2-32.txt"...]`

Also, I know that there are filenames that increment by one, like: text-1-1.txt, text-1-2.txt, text-1-3.txt,.... text-2-1.txt, text-2-2.txt,...

I have tried these two methods to try and sort the list: `new_list = sorted(filelist)` & `filelist.sort()`

Both did not work and the list came out to be the same as the original, how can I sort this list? Do I have to manually write sorting algorithms(like Bubble, or Selection)?

Answer (score 1):

You can run it this way:

```
import os

folder_path = "some path here"
filelist = os.listdir(folder_path)
filelist.sort()    #Added this line

print(filelist)
```

Comment: OP already mentioned that your suggested method is not working.

Comment: @maverick_06 Opps. Sorry I think I ignored. I tested just added one line and this worked. Maybe it still displays the old list after creating the new list?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function for this, that creates a `tuple` of `int`s from the filenames:

```
>>> def sl_no(s):
        return tuple(map(int,s.split('.')[0].rsplit('-', 2)[-2:]))

>>> sl_no("text-1-1.txt")
(1, 1)

>>> sorted(filelist, key=sl_no)
 
['text-1-1.txt',
 'txt-1-10.txt',
 'txt-1-23.txt',
 'txt-1-32.txt',
 'txt-2-1.txt',
 'txt-2-32.txt']
```

Or, you can use `re`:

```
>>> import re
>>> sorted(filelist, lambda x: tuple(re.findall(r'\d+', x)))

['text-1-1.txt',
 'txt-1-10.txt',
 'txt-1-23.txt',
 'txt-1-32.txt',
 'txt-2-1.txt',
 'txt-2-32.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, python already sorts strings in lexicographical order, but uppercase letters are all sorted before lowercase letters. If you want to sort strings and ignore case, then you can do

```
new_filelist = sorted(filelist, key=str.lower)
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to support all kinds of file names that contain numbers, you can define a sortKey function that will isolate the numeric parts of the names and right justify them (with leading zeros) for the purpose of sorting:

```
import re
def sortKey(n): 
    return "".join([s,f"{s:>010}"][s.isdigit()] for s in re.split(r"(\d+)",n))
```

output:

```
names = ["text-1-1.txt","txt-1-23.txt","txt-1-32.txt","txt-1-10.txt",
         "txt-2-1.txt","txt-2-32.txt"]

print(sorted(names,key=sortKey))
# ['text-1-1.txt', 'txt-1-10.txt', 'txt-1-23.txt', 'txt-1-32.txt', 
#  'txt-2-1.txt', 'txt-2-32.txt']


names = ["log2020/12/23.txt","log2021/1/3.txt","log2021/02/1.txt",
         "log2021/1/1.txt","log2021/1/13.txt"]

print(sorted(names,key=sortKey))
# ['log2020/12/23.txt', 'log2021/1/1.txt', 'log2021/1/3.txt', 
#  'log2021/1/13.txt', 'log2021/02/1.txt']
```